# Difference between HANDLE and HWND in Windows API?

Tags: winapi, hwnd, handles

I'm trying to use function `SetForegroundWindow(HWND hWnD)`. I have some handles but it's not working as parameter of above function.  My handle is a thread and I want to run it in foreground.

What are the differences between a HWND and a HANDLE?

Answer (score 44):

They are just [abstract data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type).

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `HANDLE` and `HWND` are defined as:

- `HANDLE` is a [handle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_%28computing%29) to an object.
- `HWND` is a handle to a window.

So, a `HWND` is a `HANDLE`, but not all `HANDLE`s are `HWND`. In fact:

```
typedef void *PVOID;
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
typedef HANDLE HWND;
```

## Example

You should only pass `HWND` to `SetForegroundWindow` unless you know what you are doing.

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Calculator");
SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
```

This first gets the handle to a window titled "Calculator" with `FindWindow` and then brings that window to foreground.

Comment: Those typedefs are only used if `STRICT` is not defined. If it is, an `HWND` is not defined as a `HANDLE` anymore, but as a unique and independent data type.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The `typedef` part was quoted from [the offical document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). (But I checked the header, that is defined the way you described. Thanks.)

Comment: `HWND` is certainly unrelated to `HANDLE` even if they happen to compile using the same pointer-sized type.  `HWND` is an index into a data structure in the windowing component (`user32.dll` and friends), `HANDLE` is an index into data structures in the kernel.

Answer (score 15):

A "handle" is the general term used to refer to a token that identifies a resource on the system (a menu, a DLL module, a block of memory, etc). Often referred to as a "magic cookie", it's normally returned when you first create the resource. You then pass that handle to other functions in the API responsible for processing the resource. You normally need not know what the handle is however. Sometimes it may be a pointer, other times a number, perhaps a structure, or whatever. That's why they hide it using names like HWND which is simply the handle used to identify a window (returned by the API function "CreateWindow()"). You therefore don't convert a "handle" to an HWND and back again since an HWND is already a "handle" (one that merely identifies windows you create).

Found here http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?135438-Handle-and-HWND

You can use FindWindow to get the hwnd from an application http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx

This should allow you to get the HWND provided you have the handle to what you're looking for [C++ Handle as HWND?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436918/c-handle-as-hwnd)

Comment: yep, tks!, but can i convert from handle to hwnd ?

Comment: @Thangnv This is like asking "Can I convert from `void *` to `int *` ?" It depends. What's your handle?

Comment: My handle is a thread and I want to run it in foreground, but it's not a HWND in function SetForegroundWindow(HWND hWnD).

Comment: I cast it HWND hWnD = (HWND) myHanle; That not error but I can't check it run or not.

Comment: @Thangnv `SetForegroundWindow` is an API to manipulate window, not thread.

Answer (score 11):

The HWND is also a HANDLE, but a global one.
I.e. a HWND valid in the context of one process is also valid in the context of another process.

Some undocumented info at https://winterdom.com/dev/ui/wnd/.

Comment: "but a global one" is exactly what I was looking for. Thx mate.

Comment: That link is now dead.

Comment: An `HWND` is a sort of handle, but not a `HANDLE`.

Comment: @BenVoigt both types are typedefs to pointers, therefore at the C++or OS level they are equal.