# Cython wrapping C++ WHND casting pointers

Tags: c++, cython

I try wrapping a short C++ function (displaying a windows MessageBox) with Cython and passing to this function a pointer (int) (generated by [wxPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxPython)).

Casting that pointer seems not to be working properly, at least the pointer arriving at the C++ level is different.

Where do I err?

#### File *cpp_test-cpp*

```cpp
#include "cpp_test.h"

Test::Test() {
}

Test::~Test() {
}

int Test::Message(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR lpText, LPCWSTR lpCaption, int uType) {
       printf("Test::Message Handle as seen from C++: %d\n", hWnd);
       return MessageBoxW(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
}
```

#### File *cpp_test.h*

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class Test {
    public:
    Test();
    ~Test();
    int Message(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR lpText, LPCWSTR lpCaption, int uType);
};
```

#### File *test.pxd*

```
cdef extern from "Windows.h":
    ctypedef Py_UNICODE WCHAR
    ctypedef const WCHAR* LPCWSTR
    ctypedef void* HWND

cdef extern from "cpp_test.h":
    cdef cppclass Test:
        Test()
        int Message(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR lpText, LPCWSTR lpCaption, int uType);
```

#### File *test.pyx*

```
cimport test

cdef class pyTest:
    cdef Test* thisptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        print "__cinit__"
        self.thisptr = new Test()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        print "__dealloc__"
        del self.thisptr

    cpdef PyMessage(self, HandleToWindow):
        print "pyTest::PyMessage Handle before casting :" + str(HandleToWindow)
        if HandleToWindow == "NULL":
            title = u"Windows Interop Demo - Python"
            return self.thisptr.Message(NULL, u"Hello Cython \u263a", title, 0)
        else:
            hwnd =<HWND> HandleToWindow
            print "pyTest::PyMessage after recasting to object casting: " + str(<object>hwnd)
            title = u"Windows Interop Demo - Python"
            return self.thisptr.Message(hwnd, u"Hello Cython \u263a", title, 0)
```

#### File *useTest.py*

```python
from test import pyTest

k = pyTest()

print k.PyMessage(12345)
```

Comment: Isn't it *"cpp_test.cpp"* (not *"cpp_test-cpp"*)?

Comment: WHND is likely a typo of [HWND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa). Example: *[Difference between HANDLE and HWND in Windows API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040440/difference-between-handle-and-hwnd-in-windows-api)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the cast `hwnd =<HWND> HandleToWindow` gets a pointer to the `PyObject` you passed as `HandleToWindow` rather than setting up a void pointer based on the contents of `HandleToWindow`.

One solution would be to create a Cython class

```
cdef class PyHandleToWindow:
   HWND ptr
   def __cinit__(self):
     self.ptr = NULL
```

then use that instead (in the function `PyMessage`, and anywhere else you need to pass round these handles in Python) as

```
cpdef PyMessage(self,handle_to_window):
  # code to deal with null goes here?
  hwnd = <PyHandleToWindow?>handle_to_window # note the question mark to test if the cast is valid
  return self.thisptr.Message(hwnd.ptr, u"Hello Cython \u263a", title, 0)
```

You could also pass the NULL pointer directly with this method rather than using strings.

Comment: `HWDB` ? should be `HWND`,right?

Comment: Almost certainly. The answer is quite old so I can't *actually* remember, but I don't think anything else matters sense